# Why can the logit function be written as a linear function?

Tags: logistic-regression

The logit function is

$ ln \frac{F(x)}{1-F(x)} $. According to wikipedia and the variety of materials that I have read, we can write this in linear form ($\beta_0 + \beta_1x$) for purposes of logistic regression. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression

However, the graph of this function only looks linear between $.1<p<.9$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit#/media/File:Logit.svg

When the texts write this as a linear equation, are they simply approximating and assuming that p is between .1 and .9, where it is mostly linear?

Comment: In lr, $p$ is actually represented like $\frac{e^{(\beta_0+\beta_1 x)}}{e^{(\beta_0+\beta_1 x)} + 1}$.

Comment: But that depends on writing the logit function in linear form. The logit function only appears linear in the middle values, Why can we still write it in linear form?

Comment: In classification problem, we usually try to find the posterior probability $P(y|x)$, and assign x to the most probable class. So in LR, we want to find a model that have linear boundary, logistic function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{\beta^T x}}$ is choosed to model the posterior probability, since $f(x)\in (0, 1)$. And then we find the logit function of $f(x)$ can be written in linear form, not approximated.